# POSTing to localhost:3000/api/editing/render results in error "Unable to extract editing data from request"

Tags: jss, docker, nextjs

I am doing some troubleshooting with my Sitecore(10.2.1)/NextJS(12.3.1)/JSS(20.0.3)/Docker setup. I am running my backend in Docker and my front end via `npm` on my host machine.

I am POSTing to `http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render` but I get an error:

[image: POSTMAN POST to api editing render]

```
{
    "html": "<html><body>Error: Unable to extract editing data from request. Ensure `bodyParser` middleware is enabled on your Next.js API route.</body></html>"
}
```

I do have `bodyParser` definitions, so it is not clear what the problem is.

[image: bodyParser definition]

Comment: Please add the JSS and Sitecore versions to the question. You can try increasing the bodyParser size limit to say 20mb, and check.

Comment: Thanks @VinayJadav - the versions have been added. I bumped up the size limit to 20mb, but that made no difference.

Comment: You get this error when the request body is invalid. Can you also post the request body you are using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These OOB comments in the render.js/render.ts file provide additional context:

```
/**
 * This Next.js API route is used to handle POST requests from the Sitecore Experience Editor.
 * This route should match the `serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl` in your Sitecore configuration,
 * which is set to "http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render" by default (see \sitecore\config\JssNextWeb.config).
 *
 * The `EditingRenderMiddleware` will
 *  1. Extract editing data from the Experience Editor POST request
 *  2. Stash this data (for later use in the page render request) via the `EditingDataService`, which returns a key for retrieval
 *  3. Enable Next.js Preview Mode, passing our stashed editing data key as preview data
 *  4. Invoke the actual page render request, passing along the Preview Mode cookies.
 *     This allows retrieval of the editing data in preview context (via the `EditingDataService`) - see `SitecorePagePropsFactory`
 *  5. Return the rendered page HTML to the Sitecore Experience Editor
 */

// Bump body size limit (1mb by default) for Experience Editor payload
// See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config
```

As the error message suggests, editing data is unable to be extracted from the request. Some scenarios in which you may see this error are:

- `bodyParser` middleware is not enabled on the route
- You have hit the `sizeLimit` defined in your `bodyParser` config
- The POST request lacks a request body entirely (`undefined`) -- this will 100% trigger the error described
- The POST request body is malformed

In order to troubleshoot, check your Next logs for more error details. You may see something like:

```
Error: Unable to extract editing data from request. Ensure `bodyParser` middleware is enabled on your Next.js API route.
    at extractEditingData (C:\projects\MySite\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-nextjs\dist\cjs\middleware\editing-render-middleware.js:174:15)
    at EditingRenderMiddleware.<anonymous> (C:\projects\MySite\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-nextjs\dist\cjs\middleware\editing-render-middleware.js:54:37)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\projects\MySite\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-nextjs\dist\cjs\middleware\editing-render-middleware.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\projects\MySite\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-nextjs\dist\cjs\middleware\editing-render-middleware.js:4:12)
    at EditingRenderMiddleware.handler (C:\projects\MySite\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-nextjs\dist\cjs\middleware\editing-render-middleware.js:28:38)
    at Object.apiResolver (C:\projects\MySite\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:366:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DevServer.runApi (C:\projects\MySite\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:481:9)
```

You can also print the request handler to the console like so:

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '20mb',
    },
  },
}

// Wire up the EditingRenderMiddleware handler
const handler = new EditingRenderMiddleware().getHandler();

console.log(`***HANDLER*** ${handler}`)
```

Output:

```
(req, res) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    var _e;
    const { method, query, body, headers } = req;
    sitecore_jss_1.debug.experienceEditor('editing render middleware start: %o', {
        method,
        query,
        headers,
        body,
    });
    if (method !== 'POST') {
        sitecore_jss_1.debug.experienceEditor('invalid method - sent %s expected POST', method);
        res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
        return res.status(405).json({
            html: `<html><body>Invalid request method '${method}'</body></html>`,
        });
    }
    // Validate secret
    const secret = (_e = query[editing_data_service_2.QUERY_PARAM_EDITING_SECRET]) !== null && _e !== void 0 ? 
_e : body === null || body === void 0 ? void 0 : body.jssEditingSecret;
    if (secret !== utils_1.getJssEditingSecret()) {
        sitecore_jss_1.debug.experienceEditor('invalid editing secret - sent "%s" expected "%s"', secret, utils_1.getJssEditingSecret());
        return res.status(401).json({
            html: '<html><body>Missing or invalid secret</body></html>',
        });
    }
    try {
        // Extract data from EE payload
        const editingData = extractEditingData(req);
        // Resolve server URL
        const serverUrl = this.resolveServerUrl(req);
        // Stash for use later on (i.e. within getStatic/ServerSideProps).
        // This ultimately gets stored on disk (using our EditingDataDiskCache) for compatibility with Vercel Serverless Functions.
        // Note we can't set this directly in setPreviewData since it's stored as a cookie (2KB limit)
        // https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/preview-mode#previewdata-size-limits)
        const previewData = yield this.editingDataService.setEditingData(editingData, serverUrl);
        // Enable Next.js Preview Mode, passing our preview data (i.e. editingData cache key)
        res.setPreviewData(previewData);
        // Grab the Next.js preview cookies to send on to the render request
        const cookies = res.getHeader('Set-Cookie');
        // Make actual render request for page route, passing on preview cookies.
        // Note timestamp effectively disables caching the request in Axios (no amount of cache headers seemed 
to do it)
        const requestUrl = this.resolvePageUrl(serverUrl, editingData.path);
        sitecore_jss_1.debug.experienceEditor('fetching page route for %s', editingData.path);
        const pageRes = yield this.dataFetcher
            .get(`${requestUrl}?timestamp=${Date.now()}`, {
            headers: {
                Cookie: cookies.join(';'),
            },
        })
            .catch((err) => {
            // We need to handle not found error provided by Vercel
            // for `fallback: false` pages
            if (err.response.status === 404) {
                return err.response;
            }
            throw err;
        });
        let html = pageRes.data;
        if (!html || html.length === 0) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to render html for ${requestUrl}`);
        }
        // replace phkey attribute with key attribute so that newly added renderings
        // show correct placeholders, so save and refresh won't be needed after adding each rendering
        html = html.replace(new RegExp('phkey', 'g'), 'key');
        // When SSG, Next will attempt to perform a router.replace on the client-side to inject the query string parms
        // to the router state. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v10.0.3/packages/next/client/index.tsx#L169.
        // However, this doesn't really work since at this point we're in the editor and the location.search has nothing
        // to do with the Next route/page we've rendered. Beyond the extraneous request, this can result in a 404 with
        // certain route configurations (e.g. multiple catch-all routes).
        // The following line will trick it into thinking we're SSR, thus avoiding any router.replace.
        html = html.replace(constants_1.STATIC_PROPS_ID, constants_1.SERVER_PROPS_ID);
        const body = { html };
        // Return expected JSON result
        sitecore_jss_1.debug.experienceEditor('editing render middleware end: %o', { status: 200, body });     
        res.status(200).json(body);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (error.response || error.request) {
            // Axios error, which could mean the server or page URL isn't quite right, so provide a more helpful hint
            console.info(
            // eslint-disable-next-line quotes
            "Hint: for non-standard server or Next.js route configurations, you may need to override the 'resolveServerUrl' or 'resolvePageUrl' available on the 'EditingRenderMiddleware' config.");
        }
        res.status(500).json({
            html: `<html><body>${error}</body></html>`,
        });
    }
})
```

In summary, it looks like you are hitting this in the handler as a result of an error during the call to `extractEditingData()`:

```
res.status(500).json({
  html: `<html><body>${error}</body></html>`,
);
```

Your specific issue may vary, so use the above as a guide to investigate further.